# Performance difference - Script Task

Tags: ssis

Is there any performance when using Script Task rather than other Task controls ? Whether the process will be slow or not !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it is user generated, you could certainly have a poorly designed script task that degraded package performance.

Really, it depends on the task you are using it for. There is no inherent performance penalty with using it, as there is with sort or unions.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, You stated what I was trying to in a much more elegant manner!

Answer (score 0):

Script Task performance depends a lot on what you are doing in the task.